# Проблема с BIOS — не запускается система, запускается bios

Tags: windows-7, bios

В один прекрасный момент вместо загрузки системы стала открываться BIOS.

Я в ней не очень то и разбираюсь, подскажите, возможно ли это исправить без сервиса, своими руками?

P.S. В инструкциях в интернете видел, что пунктов меню как-то больше, чем у меня (конкретно у меня только **main**, **advanced**, **boot**, **security** и **save & exit**), а там именно в отсутствующих пунктах были нужные настройки.

---

В Boot находятся:

**Boot Configuration**

*Fast Boot* .... *[Enabled]*

*Launch CSM* .... *[Disabled]*

**Boot Option Priorities**

// И здесь просто пусто

**> Delete Boot Option**

Comment: Нажмите F10 и Enter . Это должно сохранить настройки и перестанет запускать биос при загрузке.

Comment: @zalex ноут выключается и через секунду опять открывается BIOS

Comment: Такое случается если повредилась операционная система или отказал жесткий диск. Если можете сами переустановите систему. Если нет обращайтесь в сервис.

Comment: @zalex может быть почему либо сбросились настройки и bios «не знает» что конкретно запускать?

Comment: В boot посмотрите, есть ли у вас в списке жесткий диск. Действительно возможно аппаратная проблема.

Comment: @zalex Добавил в вопрос

Comment: как сказал уважаемый @coder675 возможен отказ жесткого диска. Гадать на расстоянии не благодарное дело.  Если сами не сможете разобраться, главное не обращайтесь в "сервисы" которых объявления висят на подъездах. Найдите подвальчик где нормальные ребята вам все объяснят.

Comment: @zalex короче, я провёл такой эксперимент: подключил флешку и опять включил компьютер. Естественно, BIOS не заставила себя долго ждать, но вот то, что я увидел в **boot** разъяснило все проблемы — ноутбук видит только флешку и всё. Значит вероятность того, что жёсткий диск сломан повысилась в разы. Завтра отнесу ноутбук в сервис, посмотрят там, возможно не всё так ужасно.

Comment: Да, все верно. Причин может быть несколько, как минимум. Надеюсь у вас все будет хорошо. :)

Comment: @zalex надо верить в лучшее, так сказать :D